# No shipping methods for Guest Checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, checkout, shipping-methods

I'm using PayPal express checkout on my website, and have guest checkout enabled.

When I checkout by signing up or logging in, everything works fine. The shipping methods are displayed.

But if I use PayPal express checkout, then after completing the form on PayPal, I'm being redirected to the following URL

> https://mysite.com/paypal/express/review

and the shipping methods are blank.

Here's the screenshot with template hints on.

[image]

Any thoughts on solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Near to the "Place order" Button there is a refresh button. Press it and the rates will be loaded

Comment: I have an "Update order data" button there. But I can't think of telling every user to do it.

Comment: I've been in exact the same situation.. this express checkout is a total mess..

Comment: you can write some JS that refreshes automatically on form edit etc.

Comment: Any thoughts on the JS? Working example?